# Cannot see the logs on Kibana in the logs tab

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I am running my project and after creating the index pattern and adding the log indices under the settings tab and applying it to save the changes. I go to the stream and for some reason I do not see anything in it. I then try using postman to use the get method to cause the messages to load in the logs stream but it does not. Is there a reason why that I cannot see it?

This is the logs in the discover section:

[image]

I then have the indice in the settings applied so it should populate:

[image]

But when I go to stream it does not show up, even on live streaming and using postman to send it.

[image]